# How do I get an Item from Sitecore's internal URI protocol?

Tags: sitecore-api

I have a reference to an item that uses the `sitecore:` protocol:

```
"sitecore://master/{...GUID HERE...}?lang=en&ver=0"
```

I could attempt to parse this URI manually to look up the item, but I'm pretty certain there's an existing utility somewhere to do this.

Of course, searching for `sitecore:` protocol URIs leads to a lot of answers about generating URLs from items, and that's **not** what I want in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's `Sitecore.Data.ItemUri` format. You can use

```
var itemUri = ItemUri.Parse(string itemUriString)
```

to get `ItemUri` class object and then

```
Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem(ItemUri itemUri)
```

to get the `Item`

Answer (score 5):

This is a Sitecore `ItemUri`.

In general, references in Sitecore take one of these forms:

- .ID: {DAC24EDD-44FB-42EF-9ECD-1E8DAF706386}
- .Uri: sitecore://master/{DAC24EDD-44FB-42EF-9ECD-1E8DAF706386}?lang=en&ver=1
- .DataUri: sitecore://{DAC24EDD-44FB-42EF-9ECD-1E8DAF706386}?lang=en&ver=1
- .ItemUri: sitecore://master/{DAC24EDD-44FB-42EF-9ECD-1E8DAF706386}?lang=en&ver=1
- .VersionUri: en, 1

It can be constructed from a String, like this:

```
var uri = ItemUri.Parse(yourString);
var uri = DataUri.Parse(yourString);
```

(examples)

For further reference, I blogged about this a while back. [Know your item, remember your context](http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2016/02/sitecore-decennial-series-1-know-your.html).